# word containing numericals

Tags: .net, regex

How can I recognize a word with regex which might contain numerics in it.
So I want to capture "string1", "12inches", "log4net".  But not 12/11/2011 or 18?
Unfortunetly `\b[\p{L}\d\p{M}]+\b` grabs numericals too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
    Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"\b(?=\S*[a-z])\w+\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Match matchResults = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
    while (matchResults.Success) {
        // matched text: matchResults.Value
        // match start: matchResults.Index
        // match length: matchResults.Length
        matchResults = matchResults.NextMatch();
    }
```

comes in mind.

```
"
\b          # Assert position at a word boundary
(?=         # Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead)
   \S          # Match a single character that is a “non-whitespace character”
      *           # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   [a-z]       # Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z”
)
\w          # Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, etc.)
   +           # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\b          # Assert position at a word boundary
"
```

Comment: Thanks.  Actually I have a bit tougher problem:  I need to recognize phrases by spaces or hyphens and have this:(?<=\b([\p{L}\p{M}]+|\s)\b)[\s\p{Pd}\s]+(?=\b[\p{L}\p{M}]+\b).  Left and right parenthesis mean some word (can have umlauts).  Now I see you've plugged in some forward reference too.

Comment: @Nickolodeon I think you should edit your question accordignly because my answer answers that. Please post some appropriate samples of input/output so we can help.

Comment: Well, sorry, I wanted to simplify the question, so asked just part of it I guess.  I need 1)Robocop - 3 => Robocop3. 2)Hello 2=>Hello2 3)Hello world=>Helloworld.  That is removing spaces or hyphens btwn words if none of the adjacent is a number or date.

Comment: Looks like it's working for the question posted.  Thanks alot.

Comment: @Nickolodeon I will try to figure out your other problem once I get home. I am on the way now ;)

Comment: By the way, spaces are not excluded by @"\b(?=.*[a-z])\w+\b".  So "12 inches" matches

Answer (score 0):

You want to match a word with both letters and numbers in it?  This should work: `\b(\w+\d+|\d+\w+)[\w\d]+\b`.